# How do I can get asp:Panel to work properly with asp:RadioButtonList without AutoPostBack?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm developping a form page in a WebForms application.

I have a RadioButtonList and a Panel, and I wanted the panel to open when a especific value of the RadioButtonList was selected, how do I do this?

I've tried with AutoPostBack but I didn't like how it worked (running the page again), are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the places I searched for an answer recommended using the AutoPostBack property, but I personally didn't like it and so I had to find another way for it to work and so I decided to use JavaScript/JQuery...

This is an HTML sample code of an example of a RadioButtonList and a panel that opens when a chosen option on it is clicked (the value "Required" causes it to open and "Not Required" to close in this case):

```
<div>
   <p class="space">3.2. ACCOMMODATION (*)</p>

   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="accomodation" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" Width="500px">
         <asp:ListItem Text="Not Required" Value="Not Required"></asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem Text="Required" Value="Required"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>

   <asp:Panel ID="PanelAccommodation" runat="server">
          <p>
               Number of nights (*):
               <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" runat="server" ControlToValidate="numberOfNights" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="<- Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </p>
               <asp:TextBox ID="numberOfNights" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>

                <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="FilteredTextBoxExtender1" TargetControlID="numberOfNights"
                            FilterType="Numbers" runat="server">
                </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>

                <p>Preferred Hotel:</p>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="preferredHotel" runat="server" Width="450px"></asp:TextBox>

                      <p>Preferred Hotel URL:</p>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="preferredHotelURL" runat="server" Width="450px"></asp:TextBox>
      </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The Script I used:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").hide("fast");
    $('#<%= accomodation.ClientID%>').find('input:radio').click(function () {
          var selVal = $('#<%= accomodation.ClientID %>').find('input:checked').val();
          if (selVal == "Required") {
               $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").show("fast");
          }
          if (selVal == "Not Required") {
               $("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").hide("fast");
          }
     })
});
```

In this Script I use the first

```
$("#MainContent_PanelAccommodation").hide("fast");
```

to make sure that when the page runs the panel is hidden and will only open when/if "Required" is selected...

Another thing you may struggle with is what ID to put in the function since as you can see the panel ID is "PanelAccommodation", but the ID I use in the function is "MainContent_PanelAccommodation" since that's how it's recognized on your browser (to check this just select the panel's position and inspect element) you'll notice that the ID becomes "MainContent_PanelAccommodation" because it inherits from your asp:Content ContentHolderID...

Hope this helps ;) any questions just ask...

Comment: You asked a question and posted an answer by yourself in less than a minute. Is this point scoring

Comment: I asked some friends how I could do something like this post the answer to help other people when they search for something similar and they told me to do it like this, because when I was trying to do this there were no posts on stack about it that worked like I wanted it too so I just put this here to help other people I even say so in the question that I'm not asking just putting this here to help others... is this not the correct way to do it?

Comment: @VítorMartins You're welcome to post your own answer if you believe it to be accurate and helpful, though the question should still follow the guidelines in "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" This Q&A is currently rather lopsided with probably too much of the information revealed only in the answer.

Comment: The answer also should contain an explanation rather than just a code dump, and the code should be pared down to the minimum needed to get the point across.

Comment: But for a good question shouldn't I was post the code I have that doesn't work and what I'm trying? how do I do that having a functioning code?

Comment: @VítorMartins No one said you didn't have functioning code. I am saying you have too much, which clouds the actual solution. You also have no explanation as to what your solution does.

Comment: Self answer is not a problem here. I am wondering is it OK to post a question for which you have already an answer?

Comment: The point of this was to help people who had the same question as me, because I had this question and seached for the answer and couldn't find any so I put this here for people on the same situation... Just trying to help ;)

Comment: @husnain_sys Yes, it is. The [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) form has an option for "Answer your own question" that allows posting both at the same time and [the blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) linked next to the option also states it.

Comment: Why are people downvoting my answer? what's wrong? I'm new here please explain and I'll improve the answer and be better on future answers